# Single Sign-on or login via in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, authentication

Which is the simplest and best free tool(php) that provides "single sign-on" i.e login via many sites.

It should provide me basic details of users like name dob, location etc. It should be completely free irrespective of site traffic. It should have facebook, twitter, google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are the reliable and/or viable and very simple to implement solutions

- https://www.simpleauth.com/
- https://rpxnow.com/signup_landing_basic (free basic version)
- http://openid.net/developers/
- http://www.gigya.com/public/platform/Register.aspx (not free)

Answer (score 1):

If you want all in one, than [**OpenID**](http://openid.net/) is your solution. OpenID's free service is shared service. Users must have OpenID account first to be able to login with this service.

If you don't want shared option, if you want this SSO (Single Sign On) service only for your own use then [**OpenID**](http://openid.net/) provides paid service. It was $0.25 per user last time I checked.

This means if everyday 100 new members will register to your websites (considering few websites, it should be the minimum), you will have to pay **$25** every day to **OpenID**.

SSO is very useful technology. You can either create your own or go with paid services. Free services for sure will be shared. If you want to create your own, security measures must be first priority.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID is extremely well know, or Facebook since it has so many users :)

Answer (score -1):

Facebook... This will become your drivers license of the internet btw :P

Comment: Please read the question my friend. Web Developer is asking for  facebook, twitter, google all-in-one tool. Not Facebook only.